# How find what plugins load google Font and block it

Tags: google, fonts

I'm currently using Zeen theme and a couple of other plugins. I've checked all the settings of the plugins and I've disabled all the voices about Google Font.

Now, my theme loads a font via CSS but, checking my [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/thegroovecartel.com/lm1FYlh2) the site load more than 10 .woff fonts from fonts.gstatic.com .

At the moment I'm delaying the load of the fonts via this JS script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Playfair+Display:700,italic,400|Open+Sans:400,700|Montserrat:400,700' ] }
    };

    (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Is there a way to find out which plugin are loading the fonts or a PHP function to insert in the function.php to block the loading of fonts from fonts.gstatic.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeen theme has a Typography section where it loads all the fonts

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will help you find the plugins or themes that might be calling this up. gstatic.com with recaptcha was driving me crazy.  fonts were a secondary problem.  (I discovered that using Google Sitekit to connect google analytics, adsense, Page tools etc, was the culprit/problem).

Google's own plugin was sabotaging my speed and score on Google Pagespeed Insights.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/